# Number of shortest path between two nodes of given undirected-connected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, graph-theory

Here is the link to problem

https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/hiring/american-express-technology-software-engineer-2019-batch/algorithm/number-of-shortest-path-046c75d6/

I am not able to understand how should I approach this problem.

Comment: Please include the specific problem/question in your post. Also that link requires login...

Answer (score 0):

If graph is acyclic you can solve this only with topological sort. You need to sort graph from your begin vertex, after that you need to calc answer for all vertexes by order of topological sort. Answer for vertex will be sum of answers all his parents from incoming edges.
If graph is cyclic you can solve this problem with search of max flow. Your source will be begin, and sink will be end. After that answer will be max flow between this two vertexes.